# FATAL SIGSEGV Error while evaluating jasper report in 6.2.0 version / JDK 11.0.18

Tags: java, memory, jasper-reports, fatal-error

I'm getting a fatal error by the JVM when trying to execute a simple jar that generates a report on production. The app has been tested on different environments however it only fails in production. I haven't been able to find any information on this error, so if anyone can point me in the right direction to fix it. The log dump:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa724815d3b, pid=1793143, tid=1808928

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.18.0.10-2.el8_7) (11.0.18+10) (build 11.0.18+10-LTS)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.18.0.10-2.el8_7) (11.0.18+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, parallel gc, linux-amd64)
Problematic frame:
 jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(B)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReport;+25

 Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e" (or dumping to /home/fne/core.1793133)

An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /home/hpe/hs_err_pid179314223.log
Compiled method (c1) 51167637 9534       1       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport::getNoData (5 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007fa72c715a90,0x00007fa72c715d48] = 696
 relocation     [0x00007fa72c715c08,0x00007fa72c715c28] = 32
 main code      [0x00007fa72c715c40,0x00007fa72c715ce0] = 160
 stub code      [0x00007fa72c715ce0,0x00007fa72c715d10] = 48
 oops           [0x00007fa72c715d10,0x00007fa72c715d18] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00007fa72c715d18,0x00007fa72c715d20] = 8
 scopes pcs     [0x00007fa72c715d20,0x00007fa72c715d40] = 32
 dependencies   [0x00007fa72c715d40,0x00007fa72c715d48] = 8
Could not load hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%208&component=java-11-openjdk


Stack: [0x00007fa6ddc6d000,0x00007fa6ddd6e000],  sp=0x00007fa6ddd69e70,  free space=1011k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(B)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReport;+25
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(B)V+13
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(B)V+25
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(B)V+39
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(B)V+11
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRFillBand;B)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/SavePoint;+2
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail()V+210
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart()V+79
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport()V+13
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(Ljava/util/Map;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint;+313
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/sql/Connection;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint;+20
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReportsContext;Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReport;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/sql/Connection;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint;+14
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReport;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/sql/Connection;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint;+7
jnet.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReport;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/sql/Connection;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint;+6
jServices.modules.jasperReports.ReportBuilder.buildReport(LsServices/modules/jasperReports/JasperReportObject;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint;+112
```

Comment: Bug in library? (https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/issues/304)